# How to pass the data from one component to other component in AEM

Tags: aem

Can anyone give me an idea of how to do it,

I have created two components, "component 1 & component 2" 
Now i have to interconnect these two components,  What i mean is "i have a checkbox in component 1, the information of component 2 ( title ) should be displayed only if I enable that checkbox from component 1.

I should use java for this.

Comment: Actually, with this solution i couldn't solve it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but it doesn't sound like a good idea. Here's some food for thought that may help you narrow down the question. Do those components have a 1 to 1 relationship of some kind? What happens when you place more than one component of each kind on the same page? Does checking the checkbox only affect the other component on the same page? Or is it supposed to be more of a feature toggle driving the behavior of another component across a wider array of pages (such as a site)?

Comment: Is it important for the contents of the second component to be hidden/rendered at the back-end? Is the checkbox a piece of AEM authoring interface in a dialog somewhere? Or is it supposed to be visible on the published page and clicked by visitors? If these components are part of an HTML form and the data isn't user-specific, it may be easier and better from the caching perspective to render both components in the page source, hide one with CSS and show it using JavaScript if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: And if you're intent on doing this in Java, keep in mind that the tricky part about having one component read data from another one is that it introduces a dependency that may be difficult for content authors to understand and very prone to breaking. AEM's WYSIWYG interface is very flexible in driving not just the layout of the page, but also the underlying content structure. There's a number of tools in AEM that could make this more manageable but I can't recommend one without reading a little more about what you're trying to build.

Comment: Hi @toniedzwiedz thanks, i resolved these issue.

Comment: Hey @Venu can you post your solution for this issue?